# Filter nullable column for nullable parameter SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `StartDate` & `EndDate` columns in a table, which they are nullable, I will pass two parameters to stored procedure to filter that table, the parameters can be null values and the columns also are nullable as I have mentioned.

How can I write a SQL statement in this case with a conditional `WHERE` clause to get the dates greater or equal to `StartDate` and the dates less than or equal to `EndDate`?

Here's what I have done so far:

```
SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM Table1
WHERE     (StartDate >= Convert(DateTime, @dtFrom) OR StartDate IS NOT NULL ) AND 
      (EndDate <= Convert(DateTime, @dtTo) OR EndDate IS NOT NULL )
```

Comment: It isn't clear what should happen when StartDate is null and `@dtfrom` isn't and when StartDate isn't null and `@dtfrom` is and when StartDate and `@dtfrom` are both null.

Comment: I second @xanatos question. Does null parm mean to look for only null? Does it mean to select any date? Or...?

Comment: @xanatos If `StartDate` is null and `@dtFrom` isn't, it should filter according to `@dtFrom` if vice-versa it shouldn't filter according the parameter, both null should get everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If null parameters means 'don't filter on that parameter' and null values in columns means positive/negative infinity, this is query you may want to use:

```
select StartDate, EndDate
from Table1
where 
   (@dtFrom is null or StartDate is null or StartDate >= Convert(DateTime, @dtFrom)) and 
   (@dtTo is null or EndDate is null or EndDate <= Convert(DateTime, @dtTo))
```